# Django view is not creating records in Database

Tags: python, html, django, foreign-keys, admin

i am not able to create record in a table FinTransDetail by admin: when I trying to add records I am getting errors. Please help to solve the issues. As I could not add by admin I can not add records by my View as well. But I can add record in FinTransHeader both by admin and by me view.

Model:

```
 class FinTransHeader(models.Model):
"""Model representing a book (but not a specific copy of a book)."""
fh_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
fh_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
fh_no = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 0,unique=True)
fh_dt = models.DateField()
fh_detail=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
fh_cust_code = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
fh_user_code =models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
fh_ref=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='nil',blank=True,null=True)
fh_status=models.CharField(max_length=1,default=0)
fh_post_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
th_prt_status=models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the Model object."""
    return str(self.fh_code)
    # return self.fh_no

 class FinTransDetail(models.Model):
fd_no = models.ForeignKey( FinTransHeader,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fd_acct = models.ForeignKey(AccountMaster, to_field='AcctCode',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fd_debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
fd_credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
fd_detail=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True )
fd_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
fd_posting=models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the Model object."""
    # return self.ToString(AcctCode)+"-"+self.AcctName
    return str(self.fd_no)
```

when I am trying to add records in FinTransDetail i am getting Html error as below:

```
 TypeError at /admin/waccounts/fintransdetail/add/
 __str__ returned non-string (type int)
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/waccounts/fintransdetail/add/
  Django Version:   3.1.1
  Exception Type:   TypeError
 Exception Value:   
 __str__ returned non-string (type int)
  Exception Location:   C:\Users\ESHACK.TOSHIBA-HOME\PycharmProjects\milestone1_udemy\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\django\forms\models.py, line 1240, in label_from_instance
 Python Executable: C:\Users\ESHACK.TOSHIBA- 
HOME\PycharmProjects\milestone1_udemy\venv\Scripts\python.exe
  Python Version:   3.7.4
  Python Path:  
 ['C:\\MY DATA FOLDER THOSHIBA\\MY FIELS_SYN_DOCSTOGO\\Django Projects',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.2.6\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'C:\\Users\\ESHACK.TOSHIBA-HOME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\ESHACK.TOSHIBA-HOME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\ESHACK.TOSHIBA-HOME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\ESHACK.TOSHIBA-HOME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\ESHACK.TOSHIBA-HOME\\PycharmProjects\\milestone1_udemy\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\ESHACK.TOSHIBA-HOME\\PycharmProjects\\milestone1_udemy\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\ESHACK.TOSHIBA-HOME\\PycharmProjects\\milestone1_udemy\\venv\\lib\\site- 
packages\\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\ESHACK.TOSHIBA-HOME\\PycharmProjects\\milestone1_udemy\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pip- 
 19.0.3-py3.7.egg',
  'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
  '2019.2.6\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
 Server time:   Thu, 06 May 2021 15:28:06 +0000
```

Comment: Your `__str__` methods for these models look fine to me, perhaps you need to look at the model `AccountMaster`? (Since it is a foreign key it's select widget would need to use it's `__str__` method)

Answer (score 0):

In the database the column `fd_no` for `FinTransDetail` will be the value of the `FinTransHeader` object's primary key. This will be an integer.

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.fd_no
```

Returning `self.fd_no` will return that integer value.

I think you are expecting the `__str__` function of `FinTransDetail` to call the `__str__` function of `FinTransHeader` because it is a foreign key but if you want to get the `fh_code` value instead use

```py
# FinTransDetail class
def __str__(self):
    return self.fd_no.fh_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **str** methods for these models look fine to me, perhaps you need to look at the model AccountMaster? (Since it is a foreign key it's select widget would need to use it's **str** method) – Abdul Aziz Barkat 14 hours ago

MR.Abdul Aziz Barkat is right. I corrected Account Master and it is adding records. Thanks